# Mongodb x.509 :'No verified subject name available from client'

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl-certificate, x509

I have following issue, trying to connect to mongoDB based on certificate login. Getting below error. Can anyone help me what went wrong with the below code.

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'No verified subject name available from client' on server pl-0-eu-central-1.dhcnl.mongodb.net:1034. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "No verified subject name available from client", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1698985993, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "d9Hebf8UbI9S34obNbGQRBwvQtw=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7263984866675392522}}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1698985993, "i": 1}}}
```

And Java code :

public @Bean
MongoClient mongoClient() {

```
    MongoClientSettings.Builder mongoClientOptions = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true).invalidHostNameAllowed(true));

    try {

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        try (InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("keystore.pkcs12").getInputStream()) {
            keystore.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
       mongoClientOptions.applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true).context(sslContext));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String user ="CN=sample,OU=Webservice,O=org,C=IN";
   // String uri="mongodb+srv://hostname/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509";
    String uri = "mongodb://hostname/?ssl=true&authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(
            MongoClientSettings.builder().credential(MongoCredential.createMongoX509Credential(user)).applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(uri))

                    .applicationName("Sample Service")

                    .retryWrites(true)
                    .build());
    return mongoClient;
}
```

Comment: Did you create the user? See [Add x.509 Certificate subject as a User](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/#add-x-509-certificate-subject-as-a-user)